# Java - How do i sort 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, double

I got a question about sorting an array.

i got an array like this:

```
long[][] allDate = new long[lenght][2];
```

and the valus are:
`allDate[][0]` represend date in miliseconds
and `allDate[][1]` represend value in this case its price of date from before
for example

```
allDate[0][0] = 142142141
allDate[0][1] = 90
```

`allDate[][0]` value of date is always in future from now
and what i want to do is to sort this dates in ascending chronological logic.
but the problem is i want to keep their price so i could do add it to my Jfreechart line chart.

in this loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < a7; i++) {
        int day = (int) (new Date().getTime() + allDate[i][0] / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        int month = (int) (new Date().getTime() + allDate[i][0] / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int year = (int) (new Date().getTime() + allDate[i][0] / (1000 * 60));
        s1.add(new Day(day, month, year), (eWallet + allDate[i][1]));
    }
```

any ideas how to sort it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and the valus are: allDate[][0] represend date in miliseconds and allDate[][1] represend value in this case its price of date from before

So the *first* thing I'd do is avoid storing those as a 2D array. Instead, store a 1D collection (whether that's an array or a list) of the pair of values:

```
PriceSnapshot[] prices = ...;
```

Where `PriceSnapshot` would consist of a timestamp (whether that's as a `long`, a `Date`, a Joda Time `Instant` etc or whatever) and a price.

At that point, you can easily write a `Comparer<PriceSnapshot>` to compare by time, and sort using that. Of course you could write a `Comparer<long[]>` instead, but that wouldn't be nearly as nice.

(Also note that with your current loop, you're taking "the current time" 3 times, which means you could end up with different dates. Bad idea. Take a *single* snapshot of "now" and then use that repeatedly.)

Comment: @user2160958: Which part? I've suggested multiple steps here. The very first thing to do is create a new class to represent the two values you're talking about. Do you understand that part?

Comment: so the class contain to fields (array or list) ? and i store data for one object ?

Comment: @user2160958: The class would just have two fields - the timestamp and the price for one entry. That way you can avoid creating a 2D array.

Comment: and something like this would work ?


      <pre>Collections.sort(allDate, new Comparator<Long[]>()
        {
            public int compare(Long[] o1, Long[] o2) {
                return o2[0].compareTo(o1[0]);
            }
        });</code>

Comment: @user2160958: No, because you've got a `long[]` rather than a `Long[]`. They're different. After that change, it would work - but it would be nasty code. You should *really, really* get away from storing these in a 2D array.

Comment: how to put my code in code tags ? xD
and if i change Long[] to long[] ?

Comment: @user2160958: Use backticks, just like you did in your question... Then read the rest of my response to your previous comment.

Comment: `Collections.sort(allDate, new Comparator<long[]>()
        {
            public int compare(long[] o1, long[] o2) {
                return o2[0].compareTo(o1[0]);
            }
        });`

it says cannot resolve method 'compareTo(long)'

Comment: @user2160958: Why are you still going with an approach which I've said repeatedly is nastier? If you **really** want to keep going with horrible code, look at `Long.compare(long, long)` - but I don't know how many more times I can say that you should be encapsulating those values in a class...

Comment: i got a lot of nasty code and its problematic now to change all my functions its easier just add this nasty sort.
`Long.compare(long, long)` still says `cannot resolve method 'Long.compare(long, long)' `

Comment: @user2160958: Well you could use `new Long(...).compareTo(...)` or implement the comparison yourself using `<`. (Presuambly you're not using Java 1.7, hence the lack of `Long.compare`.) But you're only thinking of the short term gain. You should take the time to fix things - otherwise your code base will just get worse and worse.

Comment: i installed 1,7 jdk
`Collections.sort(allDate, new Comparator<long[]>()
        {
            public int compare(long[] o1, long[] o2) {
                return Long.compare(o2[0], o1[0]);
            }
        });` i did like this and it still wont work
says `sort(java.util.List<long[][]>, Comparator<? super long[]>) in Collections cannot be applied to (long[][], Comperator<long[]>)`

Comment: You don't *have* a `List<long[][]>`. You have a `long[][]`. You should be using `Arrays.sort`. Or actually, you shouldn't be using an array at all, as I've said many times...